"Transferir" el historial de cambios de un repositorio a otro con git y github de una sola rama
Esta es la situación. Tengo dos repos. V1 y V2. Separados en github. V2 es una actualización mayor pero con la base de V1. Hice cambios en V2, y a hora voy a publicar la V3, el tema es que por comodidad en lugar de crear un repo V3 solo voy a crear una nueva rama y reajustar el repositorio de V2 de esta manera:
Repo V1 => V1

Repo V2 => RENOMBRADO - MI-APP
    \_ rama v2
       \_ rama v3    

Ahora, necesito seguir dando mantenimiento a V2 y V3 y me di cuenta que también a V1. Entonces, hice un cambio en V1, que es un fix menor y lo quiero jalar al Repo MI-APP para aplicarlo a las ramas V2 y V3. Esto va a ser constante, por eso mi idea es migrar todo el historial (aunque sea solo una rama) del repo V1 a Repo MI-APP en una nueva rama V1. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto? Intente hacer un PullRequest desde V1 a MI-APP pero no hay nada que comparar.
Esperaría algo así:
Repo MI-APP
    \_ rama v2
       \_ rama v3
    \_ rama v1
    


si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Para una rama tendrias que ejecutar una serie de comandos... no existe un solo comando que lo haga, ejemplo:
# Clonar los repositorios
git clone https://github.com/tu-usuario/mi-app.git
git clone https://github.com/tu-usuario/v1.git

# Entrar en el directorio de mi-app
cd mi-app

# Agregar v1 como remoto
git remote add v1-repo https://github.com/tu-usuario/v1.git

# Obtener las ramas de v1
git fetch v1-repo

# Crear una nueva rama v1 en mi-app desde la rama main de v1
git checkout -b v1 v1-repo/main

# Subir la nueva rama v1 al repositorio mi-app
git push origin v1

# Fusionar cambios de v1 a v2
git checkout v2
git merge v1
git push origin v2

# Fusionar cambios de v1 a v3
git checkout v3
git merge v1
git push origin v3

He agregado en cada bloque el comentario de lo que se espera que suceda. al finalizar, habrás transferido el historial de cambios de una rama de V1 a MI-APP y podrás mantener las ramas sincronizadas según sea necesario.
ESto es As-Is no tengo con que validarlo ahora mismo.

Leiste la respuesta bien? Generar las respuestas con IA no garantizan buena calidad. La última parte de la repuesta fusiona cambios con las otras ramas y eso no es parte de lo que quiero hacer.

lo hice a pulzo copeando del historial de github ... que no se parte de lo que quieras hacer no quiere decir que no lo pueda incluir como posibles acciones a realizar por el usuario ... normalmente siempre meto un extra u otras formas metodos para hacer las cosas ... podras ver ese patron en todas mis respuestas ...

en fin si no quieres fusionar las ramas , no lo hagas ... jajajaja a alguien le ha de servir ...
